# How can add a Custom filter / Custom search field to Sale Order view based on a field in the partner form

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-view

I have a field `card_customer` in partner form. What i need is i have to add a custom filter for sale orders based on the field `card_customer`. When choosing this filter i need the sale orders, which have customers with `card_customer` field equaling `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter in search view, by inheriting the base search view of sale order ,and create a new view.

```
<data>
    <record id="sale_order_search_inherit_receipt" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.search.receipt</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.sale_order_view_search_inherit_quotation"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//filter[@name='order_confirmed']" position="after"> // Adding the filter after existing filter 'Confirmed Orders'
                <separator/>
                <filter string="Card Customer" name="is_card_customer" domain="[('partner_id.card_customer','=', True)]"/>
                <separator/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's possible by creating the filter "technically". A normal user can't do that in vanilla Odoo sofar. Hopefully that feature will come one day.

"Technically" means either in a custom module or by using the debug mode in the client. Odoo can use dot-Notation in domains on such filters. And an admin can use this to create a custom filter directly in the client.

**Creating in debug mode**

1. active the debug mode
2. either go to Settings/Technical/user-defined filters OR open "Manage filters" in the debug context menu in the sales order list view

[image]

3. create the filter

[image]

**Create a filter in custom module**

```xml
  <record id="my_customer_filter" model="ir.filters">
    <field name="action_id" eval="False"/>
    <field name="active" eval="True"/>
    <field name="context">{}</field>
    <field name="domain">[["partner_id.card_customer","=",True]]</field>
    <field name="is_default" eval="True"/>
    <field name="model_id">sale.order</field>
    <field name="name">cart_customer is true</field>
    <field name="sort">[]</field>
  </record>
```

**Create a filter in search view in a custom module**

```xml
        <record id="view_sales_order_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sale.order.list.select</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_filter" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <filter name="need_message" position="after">
                    <filter name="filter_card_customer_true" string="card_customer is true"
                        domain="[('partner_id.card_customer','=',True)]" />
                </filter>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: I was thinking maybe <field name="name">sale.order.list.select</field> should be changed e.g. to <field name="name">sale.order.list.customer_true</field>; since the term 'select' is kind of confusing here. Or I just don't know how to select with a filter : 6

Comment: Hi, you can change the name of a view to whatever you want. IIRC i just copied the code from Odoo itself, where they (odoo employees) usually name those search views something with "select" in it. But yes i'm on your side, sometimes it's better to name a view if possible by their intention. And this example here could be like your suggestion or like "sale.order.filter.card_customer" or similar names.

Comment: ohh yes, it's in the sale_views.xml :);
I am just quite a novice with odoo, and I was thinking pressing the filter button will select the rows as well.